# What commands cannot go together with the cmd command in one line / in Windows RUN box?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am testing out some code in the Windows RUN box. Now, I know there is no need to do it that way for long codes and that I could simply put the code in a batch file and then run it via the RUN box or the cmd box.

Regardless, I am curious about **what cmd commands can be executed from the RUN box and if there is a limit to the number of commands**.

I have searched online but can't find any site that goes into detail about this.

For example, in the run box, I enter:

`cmd /k echo hello & Call :abc & goto :eof & :abc & echo I belong to abc`

after hello is echoed, I then get an error message of "Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script."

Is that error message because the code is structured incorrectly or because labels and calls to labels as well as `goto` commands are not allowed? What about for loops? Any other ones?

P.S. Just in case this might be helpful, I am using Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call or goto a label in a single line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jaap: please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254296/would-very-short-correct-answers-be-better-left-as-comments